# Universal connection Pool shuts down automatically before application shutdown hook executes

Tags: java, shutdown-hook, ucp

I have my java application running on jetty which uses JDBC (uses UCP) to make database connection. Problem I am facing is during jetty shutdown, before my application shutdown hook executes, UCP goes on auto shutdown which is not desired since I want to do some predestroy stuff during that time and explicitly want to shut down database connection factories. Can any one help me here please ? or let me know why is it so?